# Speed up TensorFlow object detection inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, multiprocessing

I started running my own trained model inference on a 3,600 frames when I noticed inference time per frame is 1.2-2 seconds. All process took about two hours. I checked the performace and saw that cpu use is 10%-15% gpu use is 1%-5% and only one process running. First thing got to my mind is to use multiprocessing to speed up the whole thing but, I run into an error. Code is as follow:

```
    # # Object Detection Image
# Welcome to the object detection inference walkthrough!
# This notebook will walk you step by step through the process of using a pre-trained model to detect objects in an image.
# Make sure to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) before you start.

# # Imports

import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import multiprocessing
import time

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.12.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.12.*.')


# ## Env setup
# This is needed to display the images.
# get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# Model preparation

# ## Variables

# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH` to point to a new .pb file.

# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo]
# (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
# for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v0_walrus_13_12_2019'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
# DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
# PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'ssd_mobilenet_v0_walrus_13_12_2019_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 5



# ## Download Model
# opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
# opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
# tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
# for file in tar_file.getmembers():
#   file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
#   if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
#     tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

# ## Helper code

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

# # Detection

def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: image})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.int64)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict


# Size, in inches, of the output images.
# IMAGE_SIZE = (18, 12)

# for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
def detector(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
    # result image with boxes and labels on it.
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    # Actual detection.
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np_expanded, detection_graph)
    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        output_dict['detection_boxes'],
        output_dict['detection_classes'],
        output_dict['detection_scores'],
        category_index,
        instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)
    # plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
    # plt.imshow(image_np)

    #save to same folder as data input
    img = Image.fromarray(image_np)
    img.save(r'C:\temp\detected_frames\image{}.jpg'.format(image_path[len(image_path)-6:len(image_path)-4]))

# Load images:
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = r'C:\temp\frames'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(17, 20) ]

n_cpu = 6
start_time = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = n_cpu)
    pool.map(detector, TEST_IMAGE_PATHS, chunksize = 1)
    pool.close()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('time with multiprocessing: ',elapsed_time)
```

**This is the error:**

> ```
>     C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection>python
> ```
>
> image_mp_object_detection.py
>       WARNING:tensorflow:From image_mp_object_detection.py:86: The name tf.GraphDef is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphDef instead.
>
> ```
> WARNING:tensorflow:From image_mp_object_detection.py:87: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:86:
> ```
>
> The name tf.GraphDef is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphDef
>   instead.
>
> ```
> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:86:
> ```
>
> The name tf.GraphDef is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphDef
>   instead.
>       WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:87:
>   The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile
>   instead.
>
> ```
> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:87:
> ```
>
> The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile
>   instead.
>
> ```
> WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:110:
> ```
>
> The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session
>   instead.
>
> ```
> 2019-12-19 10:59:53.893730: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
> ```
>
> Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
>       WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:110:
>   The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session
>   instead.
>
> ```
> 2019-12-19 10:59:53.898838: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
> ```
>
> Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
>       2019-12-19 21001:95-91:25-31.99 41705:8559:: 5I3 .t9e4n7s5o8r5f:l oIw
>   /tceonrseo/rcfolmomwo/nc_orruen/tciommem/ognp_ur/ugnptui_mdee/vgipcue/.gcpcu:_1d6e4v0i]c
>   eF.ocucn:d1 6d4e0v]i cFeo u0n dw idtehv ipcreo p0e rwtiitehs :p r
>       onpaemret:i eGse:F o
>       rncaem eR:T XG e2F0o8r0c em aRjToXr :2 078 0m imnaojro:r :5  7m emmionroyrC:l o5c kmReamtoer(yGCHlzo)c:k R1a.t7e1(
>       GpHczi)B:u s1I.D7:1
>       0p0c0i0B:u0s1I:D0:0 .000
>       0200:1091-:1020-.109
>        21001:95-91:25-31.99 51708:7509:: 5I3 .t9e5n8s4o7r5f:l oIw /tsetnrseoarmf_leoxwe/csuttroera/mp_leaxtefcourtmo/rd/epflaautlfto/rdml/odpeefna_uclhte/cdkleorp_esnt_ucbh.eccck:e2r5_]s
>   tGuPbU. clci:b2r5a]r iGePsU  alrieb rsatraiteisc aalrley 
>   sltiantkiecda,l lsyk ilpi ndkleodp,e ns kcihpe cdkl.o
>       pen check.
>       201290-1192--1129- 1190 :1509::5593:.5936.49968542:3 0I:  tIe ntseonrsfolrofwl/ocwo/rceo/rceo/mcmoomnm_ornu_nrtuinmtei/mgepu//ggppuu/_gdpeuv_idceev.iccce:.1c7c6:31]7
>   6A3d]d iAndgd ivnigs ivbilsei bglpeu  gdpeuv idceevsi:c e0s
>       : 0
>       2019-12-19 10:59:5230.1997-11228-51:9  I1 0t:e5n9s:o5r3f.l9o7w1/2c8o6r:e /Ip
>   ltaetnfsoorrmf/lcopwu/_cfoeraet/uprlea_tgfuoarrmd/.ccpcu:_1f4e2a]t
>   uYroeu_rg uCaPrUd .scucp:p1o4r2t]s  Yionusrt rCuctionPsU  tshuaptp
>   otrhtiss  iTnesntsrourcFtlioown sb itnhaarty  twhaiss  nToetn
>   scoormFpliolwe db itnoa ruys ew:a sA VnXo2t
>        compiled to use: AVX2
>       2019-12-19 10:59:53.980383: 2I0 1t9e-n1s2o-r1f9l o1w0/:c5o9r:e5/3c.o9m8m0o8n7_8r:u nIt
>   itmensore/gpu/gpu_defvliocwe/.ccocr:e1/6c4o0m]m oFno_urnudn
>   tdeivmiec/eg p0u /wgiptuh_ dpervoipceer.tcice:s1640] F:o u
>       nnda mdee:v iGceeF o0r cwei tRhT Xp r2o0p8e0r tmiaejso:r :
>        n7a mmei:n oGre:F o5r cmee mRoTrXy C2l0o8c0k Rmaatjeo(rG:H z7) :m i1n.o7r1:
>        p5c imBeumsoIrDy:C l0o0c0k0R:a0t1e:(0G0H.z0)
>       :2 011.97-11
>       2p-c1i9B u1s0I:D5:9 :05030.09:80816:7060:. 0I
>        2t0e1n9s-o1r2f-l1o9w /1s0t:r5e9a:m5_3e.x9e9c0u2t1o0r:/ pIl attefnosromr/fdleofwa/uslttr/edalmo_peexne_ccuhteocrk/eprl_asttfuobr.mc/cd:e2f5a]u
>   lGtP/Ud lloipberna_rciheesc kaerre_ ssttuabt.iccca:l2l5y]  lGiPnUk
>   eldi,b rsakriipe sd laorpee ns tcheck.
>       atic2a0l1l9y- 1l2i-n1k9e d1,0 :s5k9i:p5 3d.l9o9p6e0n1 5c:h eIc kt.e
>       nso2r0f1l9o-w1/2c-o1r9e /1c0o:m5m9o:n5_3r.u9n9t7i4m6e9/:g pIu /tgepnus_odrefvliocwe/.ccocr:e1/7c6o3m]m oAnd_driunngt ivmies/igbplue/
>   ggppuu_ ddeevviiccee.sc:c :01
>       763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.272484: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.276416: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.278405: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.282195: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   6279 MB memory) ->20 1p9h-y1s2i-c1a9l  1G0P:U5 9(:d5e5v.i2c8e6:1 307,:
>   nIa mtee:n sGoerFfolrocwe/ cRoTrXe /2c0o8m0m,o np_criu nbtuism ei/dg:p
>   u0/0g0p0u:_0d1e:v0i0c.e0.,c cc:o1m1p8u1t]e  Dceavpiacbei liinttye:r
>   c7o.n5n)e
>       ct StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.292241: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.294398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gWARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project
>   Ready For
>   Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:112:
>   The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
>       p
>       u/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
>       2019-12-19 10:59:55.297425: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   6279 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080,
>   pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
>       WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Project Ready For Training\models\research\object_detection\image_mp_object_detection.py:112:
>   The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
>
> ```
> 2019-12-19 10:59:59.496535: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
> ```
>
> cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       2019-12-19 10:59:59.501378: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       2019-12-19 10:59:59.589089: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       2019-12-19 10:59:59.593281: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.641238: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0
>   with properties:
>       name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.71
>       pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.645818: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25]
>   GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.649715: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible
>   gpu devices: 0
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.652491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.655682: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.657640: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
>       2019-12-19 11:00:00.660369: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created
>   TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with
>   6279 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080,
>   pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
>       2019-12-19 11:00:01.925959: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       2019-12-19 11:00:01.930184: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "image_mp_object_detection.py", line 193, in 
>           pool.map(detector, TEST_IMAGE_PATHS, chunksize = 1)
>         File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
>           return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>         File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
>           raise self._value
>       multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: ''. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle _thread.RLock
>   objects",)'

Tensorflow-gpu == 1.14
Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Do you got any solution?

Comment: Not yet, I guess other people experience same problem.  I think the bottle neck is the connectivity between CPU and GPU, maybe TensorFlow team should address this performance issue.

Comment: I have seen people are using yolo3 in place of FAster-RCNN. Yolo3 is pretty fast with sightless accuracy.

Comment: Accually I'm installing darknet at this very moment, Let know how it works.